# Google Cloud Build - Self hosted bitbucket server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket

In my company we are using Google Cloud to develop our application and we'd like to use Cloud Build for CD/CI. The problem is that our Bitbucket server is self hosted, not at Bitbucket's cloud. When we try to add a new repository, Google Cloud redirects us to Bitbucket's cloud and I don't find any way to connect our company repository.

Is this currently possible?

I'm stucked in this screen:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I understand that when you say "When we try to add a new repository", you mean a new repository within [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/)

Comment: No, @Miguel, I select Bitbucket since it's a self hosted bitbucket server

Comment: In that case, it'd be helpful if you could share what you've tried so far, either by sharing a sample code or screenshots.

Comment: This isn't a code issue. I am trying to connect a repository to Google Cloud Build to automate deployments. The repository I am using is in a self-hosted Bitbucket repository. Imagine I'm trying to connect the repository ulisesceca.com/bitbucket/my-repo instead of bitbucket.com/ulises/my-repo. When I select Bitbucket on the repo selection at GCP Build, it redirects me to bitbucket.com and I can't find how to set it to be instead ulisesceca.com/bitbucket/my-repo I've edited my question to show the screen where I get stucked because of this

Comment: Right now this does not look like a supported feature for Cloud Build triggers. As per [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers#before_you_begin) your source code must be within Cloud Source Repositories, GitHub or Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Build's Bitbucket Server and Bitbucket Data Center integration is now in GCP. We can build repositories from Bitbucket Server and Bitbucket Data Center, including on-premises instances.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-bitbucket-data-center